# How to make JPanel vertical gradient?

Tags: java, swing, gradient

How to make JPanel vertical gradient. I'm using following code but it is horizontal gradient.

```
  myPanel.setUI(new PanelUI()  {
        public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(new Point(0, 0), Color.white,new Point(1612, 35), Color.black, false));
            g2.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 35);
        }
    });
```

Comment: If you cannot, in conjunction with the Java Docs, figure how to change the direction of the gradient, you need to ask yourself if you're really cut out for programming..

Comment: Try 0 instead of 1612 in the creation of the second `Point`. I haven’t tested, I’ll leave that to you.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thank you.Its working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GradientPaint.html#GradientPaint(java.awt.geom.Point2D,%20java.awt.Color,%20java.awt.geom.Point2D,%20java.awt.Color)), you're using a constructor that asks you for 2 points and 2 colors:

```
public GradientPaint(Point2D pt1,
             Color color1,
             Point2D pt2,
             Color color2)
```

Each point has its own `X` and `Y` coordinates, so it seems horizontal because you're saying in your code to paint the gradient from the point `(0, 0)` to the point `(1612, 35)` but actually it's a bit diagonal

In this case, if you want it completely vertical, either change the 1612 on P2 to 0 or change 0 on P1 to 1612

It will fill the shape based on that configuration, I think you're confused thinking it should paint from `(0, 0)` to `(1612, 35)` with the gradient, but those coords are only for the configuration of the gradient not the actual painting of it

Imagine those coords as a Cartesian map, what happens if you draw a line from `(0, 0)` to `(10, 10)`? It's a diagonal stroke, now what happens if you draw it from `(0, 0)` to `(10, 0)` or from `(10, 10)` to `(20, 10)`? It's a horizontal stroke and what's happens if you draw a line from `(0, 0)` to `(0, 10)` or from `(10, 10)` to `(10, 20)`? It's a vertical stroke. See what's the coord changing on each example?

- For **diagonal** strokes both `X` and `Y` coords change
- For **horizontal** strokes just `X` changes
- For **vertical** strokes only `Y` changes

So, that's what you need to do :)

Comment: for explanation.Before this, I was unable to understand the logic.

Comment: I'm glad it helped :) I guess there was a "tank you" (yeah I missed the `h` on purpose) before the *"for explanation"*; anyway, Happy programming